# Unable to locate nested text using XPath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am new to automation and am trying to test an unsuccessful login. On entering a wrong password an error popup window is displayed on website. I am trying to write a test to confirm the error text is displayed.

Code trials:

```
@Test
    public void IncorrectPasswordMessage() {

        boolean b=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"errors\"]/h2")).isDisplayed();
        Assert.assertTrue(b);

    }
```

The HTML is below. How could I change my script to confirm the nested text *"There are the following errors."* is shown on the webpage?

```
<form id="login_form" action="/cs/form/customer-login" method="AJAX" class="cforms pad-top1 span6">
    <!--|cid=1400679170853|type=Forms_P|-->
    <div id="errors" style="">
        <h2>There are the following errors.</h2>
        <ul><li>The number and password you have entered do not match. Please enter it again.</li></ul>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_form_url" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="_success_url" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="_failure_url" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: As per your `Assert.assertTrue()` I have replaced the `javascript` tag with `java` tag. Let me know if the change looks good.

Answer (score 0):

The element is a [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) element so to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  @Test
      public void IncorrectPasswordMessage() {
          WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#errors>h2")));
          // lines of code
          Assert.assertTrue(b);
      }
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  @Test
      public void IncorrectPasswordMessage() {
          WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='errors']/h2")));
          // lines of code
          Assert.assertTrue(b);
      }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for quick response DebanjanB. I have tried both of the locator strategies but it is returning "Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: div#errors>h2 (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)". 
When adding the locator strategies eclipse highlights an error stating "Type mismatch: cannot convert from WebElement to boolean" and I have tried both fixes for these.

Comment: @MichaelD There was an error in the code as _ExpectedConditions_ of `visibilityOfElementLocated` will always return the element and you can't consider it as a boolean. Updated the answer.